# ModSecurity CRS 3 - Disable SQLi Rule For URI Pattern

Tags: security, apache-2.4, mod-security

I am trying to disable rule 942100 (an SQLi rule) when certain values are present in the URI, but apache won't start so something is wrong.

My attempt (in REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf):

```
SecRule ARGS "@rx (m[inax]{2}[_\w]+)\-{3}[ade]{1,2}sc" \
    "id:942100,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    nolog,noauditlog,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveById=942100"
```

The idea is so that URI values such as "min_width---asc" and "max_height_or_width---desc" for example are not flagged by ModSec. I need to remove these false positives but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't remove the rule itself. As you can see, the `id` of your rule is equal what you want to remove.

If you see the original rule [here](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/ab24a20faf28156f0495b0c07f2ff37860a3defe/rules/REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf.example#L105-L110), you can see, there is a unique id (1001). Why don't you modify the operator and arguments, and remove the comment?

Eg.:

```
SecRule ARGS "@rx (m[inax]{2}[_\w]+)\-{3}[ade]{1,2}sc" \
     "id:1001,\
     phase:1,\
     pass,\
     nolog,\
     ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=942100"
```

Or you do that with a new, unique id (replace the 1001 with another unique value).

Comment: Touche. XD I will try this immediately. (Tbh I've been doing a lot of guesswork with all this, it's pretty dense for newcomers)

Comment: Yep, apache at least started. Now I will play the waiting game and keep an eye on the logs to see if everything including my regex was a success. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, you're welcome :)

Comment: It appears those particular requests stopped appearing in the logs during the past couple weeks.  So I'll call that a success.